Mathematical expression possible instead of using a (while) loop
It seems possible to execute this without using a loop, in python:
            check = -arr[i]
            while check >= mi:
                check -= k

arr[i] and mi are constants at this point.
I want to minimise the value of check such that it obeys the following:
check = (x * k) - arr[i] for some x
AND:
check >= mi
Everything here is an integer.
Obviously using a loop here is very inefficient, so I am wondering how to do it in O(1) time. The while loop code is correct for all cases, just slow.
I tried this, but it is wrong.
            x = math.ceil((mi + arr[i]) / k)
            check = x * k - arr[i]


The problem is the ">=".  That gives your code an off-by-one.  Plus, you have addition and subtraction swapped.  We need to REDUCE -arr[i] by the x*k value.
x = math.ceil((-arr[i]-mi+1)/k)
check = -arr[i] - x * k

Consider an example, where arr[i] = -14, mi = 5, k = 3.  If we do this by hand, we go 14, 11, 8, 5, 2.  So, 4 steps.  If arr[i] = -13, then there are only 3 steps:  13, 10, 7, 4.
Test app:
import math
i = 0
def f1(arr,mi,k):
    check = -arr[i]
    while check >= mi:
        check -= k
    return check
def f2(arr,mi,k):
    x = math.ceil((-arr[i]-mi+1)/k)
    check = -arr[i] - x * k
    return check

print(f1([-14],5,3))
print(f2([-14],5,3))
print(f1([-13],5,3))
print(f2([-13],5,3))

Output:
2
2
4
4

